# File not found exception in upload image on server using file body

Tags: android, exception, http-post

My requirement is to login with facebook,after login, facebook info will be my app profile info, but when i try to save my profile with facebook profile pic url,cover page image url using FileBody it gives me file not found exception, but profile pic url and cover page url works fine in browser and shows image.

Can anyone help me to come out from this.

```
public String[] saveProfile(Context context, String bannerPath, String profilePicPath, String userName)
{

String str_response = "";
String[] arryResponse = new String[2];

mContext = context;

Log.d(TAG, " --  profilePicPath -- " + profilePicPath);
Log.d(TAG, " --  bannerPath -- " + bannerPath);

if (isNetworkConnected())
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), 10000);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(baseUrl + "user/edituserprofile/");
    try
    {
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    if (profilePicPath.length() > 0)
    {
        profilePicPath = profilePicPath.replace("http", "https").toString().trim();
        File F = new File(profilePicPath);
        FileBody fb = new FileBody(F);
        reqEntity.addPart("vProfilePicture", fb);
    }

    if (bannerPath.length() > 0)
    {
        bannerPath = bannerPath.replace("http", "https").toString().trim();
        File F = new File(bannerPath.replace("http", "https"));
        FileBody fb = new FileBody(F);
        reqEntity.addPart("vCoverPicture", fb);
    }


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String x_api_key = (sharedPreferences.getString(ConstantCode.X_API_KEY, ""));

    reqEntity.addPart("vUserName", new StringBody(fullName));

    String userId = sharedPreferences.getString(ConstantCode.USER_ID, "");
    String accessToken = sharedPreferences.getString(ConstantCode.ACCESS_TOKEN, "");

    httppost.addHeader("X_API_KEY", x_api_key);
    httppost.addHeader("accesstoken", accessToken);
    httppost.addHeader("iUserID", userId);
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    str_response = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    Log.e(TAG, "  Edit Profile response  " + str_response);

    if (!str_response.equals(""))
    {
        try
        {

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str_response);

        arryResponse[0] = obj.getString("STATUS");
        arryResponse[1] = obj.getString("MESSAGE");


        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "  Edit Profile ClientProtocolException  " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "  Edit Profile IOException  " + e.toString());
    }
}
;

return arryResponse;
}
```

Comment: Post Logcat and relevant code. Is that so hard to understand?

Comment: Excuse the down voter, if you don't know the answer don't touch the question, leave it. Don't show your greatness by down voting, if you have knowledge about this give answer and prove you knowledge.

Comment: @Marius i put my code, may help me?

Comment: Include Logcat too, and highlight the part where exception occurs. I downvoted you, because Question hardly shows any research and there aren't enough details to identify the problem. If you fix those, I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i got the solution for this problem, m happy :)

Here, i am used image link of facebook profile pic,and cover Pic directly that was the main root of this problem,so i stored my image into sdcard and fetch from there and use sdcard path of that stored image an it give a smile on my face. Problem solved.

According to above code, just change the path

```
if (profilePicPath.length() > 0)
{
    File F = new File(profilePicPath);// Path from SD-Card Like '/sdcard/example/image1.jpg'
    FileBody fb = new FileBody(F);
    reqEntity.addPart("vProfilePicture", fb);
}

if (bannerPath.length() > 0)
{
    File F = new File(bannerPath);// Path from SD-Card Like '/sdcard/example/image2.jpg'
    FileBody fb = new FileBody(F);
    reqEntity.addPart("vCoverPicture", fb);
}
```